# How to get custom list view in django-rest-framework viewset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a tv channel model and created a django-restframework viewlet which gives me a list and a detail view out of the box. On top I added two custom single-object views called all_events and now_and_next_event, as described here: [Marking extra methods for routing](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets.html). That works great so far.

```
class ChannelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    A viewset for viewing and editing channel instances.
    """
    serializer_class = serializers.ChannelSerializer
    queryset = Channel.objects.all()

    @link()
    def now_and_next_event(self, request, pk):
        ''' Show current and next event of single channel. '''
        ...
```

Now I would like to add a custom view which is NOT a single-object view but a list-like view:

```
class CurrentEvents(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    ''' Show current event of all channels. '''
    model = Event
    serializer_class = serializers.EventSerializer

    def get(self, request):
        ...
```

When I disable my viewlet and add a manual url pattern for it, it works as well. But I haven't figured out how to make them both work with the same 'api/channel/' prefix, or what I would like more, how to add the custom list view class into my viewlet.

Here are my viewlet url patterns:

```
^api/channel/$ [name='channel-list']
^api/channel/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/$ [name='channel-detail']
^api/channel/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/all_events/$ [name='channel-all-events']
^api/channel/(?P<pk>[^/]+)/now_and_next_event/$ [name='channel-now-and-next-event']
```

And I would like to access my list view like:

```
^api/channel/current_events/$ [name='event-current']
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46066153/2803344

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of Django REST Framework 2.4, you can now decorate `ViewSet` methods with `@list_route` to get what you are looking for.

[From the documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing)

> The `@detail_route` decorator contains `pk` in its URL pattern and is intended for methods which require a single instance. The `@list_route` decorator is intended for methods which operate on a list of objects.

These replace the old `@link` and `@action` decorators which were only able to work as detail routes.

Comment: As of 3.8, `@detail_route` and `@list_route` are pending deprecation in favor of `@action(detail=True)` and `@action(detail=False)`. (These will be deprecated in 3.9 and removed in 3.10).

Answer (score 6):

if you want list of objects then you need list method in your ListApiView:
For example, model is ModelName and serializer class is SerializerClassname
then code will be:

```
class ExampleView(ListAPIView):
    model = ModelNmae
    serializer_class = SerializerClassName
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        """
        queryset = ModelName.objects.all()
        q = self.request.query_params.get('q', None)
        if q is not None:
            queryset =queryset.filter(name__icontains=q)
        return queryset

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        result = [ x.values()[0] for x in serializer.data ]
        return Response(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, create a `viewsets.py` file anywhere in the project and write the following code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin
from django.core.paginator import EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger, Paginator

    
class ModelOptsMixin(object):
     """CBV mixin which adds model options to the context."""
    
     def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """Returns the context data to use in this view."""
        ctx = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if hasattr(self, "model"):
            ctx["opts"] = self.model._meta
        return ctx

class BaseListView(
    LoginRequiredMixin,
    PermissionRequiredMixin,
    ModelOptsMixin,
    HasPermissionsMixin,
    ListView,
):
    """ListView CBV with LoginRequiredMixin and PermissionRequiredMixin."""

    def base_paginator(self, instance):
        """
        Set paginator return context of paginator.
        """
        paginator = Paginator(instance, int(settings.DEFAULT_PAGINATION_SIZE))
        page = self.request.GET.get("page", 1)
        try:
            instance_paginator = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            instance_paginator = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            instance_paginator = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        return instance_paginator
```

Import `BaseListView` and use this.