# User Authentication in Django REST Framework

Tags: django, angular, rest

I have a Django REST backend, and it has a `/users` endpoint where I can add new users through `POST` method from frontend.

`/users` endpoint url:

`http://192.168.201.211:8024/users/`

In this endpoint I can view all users information and add new user, so I must avoid others entry it except Administrator. I create a superuser `admin` with password `admin123` by `python manage.py createsuperuser`.

My question is, If I want to do a HTTP `POST` from frontend(I use Angular) I have to pass the Administrator's user name and password, `admin` and `admin123`, along with `POST` head information. So I let others know the user name and password who check the source code of frontend.

Is there any other way to do this `Authentication` without exposing Administrator's user name and password to others?

Comment: Why would you hardcode the admin's credentials into the frontend?

Comment: If a new user want to register instead of Administrator, how can I handle it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an API that handles the user creation. This is why we create backends. The user will send the API their credentials and the API will add the user to the database using the admin credentials and post request. The API's code will not be viewable. Depending on your needs, auth0 can be a good solution and save you time on user registration and login. If you make your own sign up and login be sure to hash passwords and make sure they are sent over SSL. A service like auth0 will handle all this for you if you want to focus on other parts of your project.

Comment: Do you mean I need to create another endpoint instead of `http://192.168.201.211:8024/users/`? Like `/create_user/`, then add new user into db by hand, not use django REST `ModelViewSet` to add use.

Comment: let's say /create_user/ receives the post request then takes that data and posts to django REST ModelViewSet to add the user.

Comment: How can we do `POST` in `view` function of Django? I mean `POST` always from frondend to backend, right?

Answer (score 0):

[token auth](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) is may what you need,i use token auth for DRF as backend and angular as frontend

Comment: I can use `token = Token.objects.create(user='admin')` to get a token of `admin` and then use this token to do a `POST` right?

Comment: user login success you need return a token to user client,after this,all the request from client need be add a header format like 'Authorization':'Token 7582b1089cb8fd605d03fe70bcd0ee7c2f7cxf14',then TokenAuthentication will identification of user identity by the header in backend

Comment: if you are new to DRF and token auth,[django-rest-framework-jwt](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt) must be help

Comment: I know `jwt`, if I log in by `admin` and the related password then I can get a token. But here I want to access the `/users/` endpoint by a new user, not `admin`. This new user does not have `admin`'s password.

Comment: I want to give this user a temporary right to access this endpoint

Comment: you can set period of validity for a token,and token auth has nothing to do with admin

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I find a method to solve this problem.

Here has a very elegant way to do this, rewrite `get_queryset` function in my UserViewSet:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    # permission_classes = (permissions.IsAdminUser, )
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny, )  # <-- change 1
    # queryset = User.objects.all()  # <-- change 2
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = User.objects.filter(id=self.request.user.id)
        if self.request.user.is_superuser:
            queryset = User.objects.all()
        return queryset
```

In change 1, permissions allowed anyone to access, so a new user can do a `POST` without any authentication.

In change 2, I only return all users when the user is superuser, just like rewrote `get_queryset` done.

Also need to change `urls.py` file to add `base_name` for this url like this:

```
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet, base_name='user')
```

ref, https://stackoverflow.com/a/22767325/2803344