# How can I add additional top level JSON fields using the ModelSerializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using the [ModelSerializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer) from the [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) to create an API. The ModelSerializer works great for returning JSON lists of whatever I query the database for. But I need to have some additional fields at the root level of the JSON response. How can I bump the query result to another level and add custom fields at the root of the JSON object?

This is what the API query returns:

```json
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "user": {
            "username": "myuser"
        },
        "content": "Another tweet",
        "timesince": "2 weeks, 3 days",
        "url": "/tweet/3/",
        "id": 3
    },
    {
        "user": {
            "username": "myuser"
        },
        "content": "a tweet",
        "timesince": "2 weeks, 3 days",
        "url": "/tweet/2/",
        "id": 2
    }
]
```

This is what I want:

```json
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "custom_field": "custom value",
    "result": [
            {
                "user": {
                    "username": "myuser"
                },
                "content": "Another tweet",
                "timesince": "2 weeks, 3 days",
                "url": "/tweet/3/",
                "id": 3
            },
            {
                "user": {
                    "username": "myuser"
                },
                "content": "a tweet",
                "timesince": "2 weeks, 3 days",
                "url": "/tweet/2/",
                "id": 2
            }
    ]
}
```

serializer.py:

```
from django.utils.timesince import timesince

from rest_framework import serializers

from tweets.models import Tweet
from accounts.api.serializers import UserDisplaySerializer

class TweetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserDisplaySerializer(read_only=True)
    timesince = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    url = serializers.CharField(source='get_absolute_url', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Tweet
        fields = [
            'user',
            'content',
            'timesince',
            'url',
            'id',
            ]

    def get_timesince(self, obj):
        return timesince(obj.created)
```

views.py:

```
from django.db.models import Q
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework import exceptions
from rest_framework import permissions

from tweets.models import Tweet
from tweets.api import serializers

class TweetListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.TweetSerializer

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = Tweet.objects.all()
        queryset = queryset.order_by('-id')

        return queryset
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by overriding the `list` method of the `ListAPIView` and then adding this new field to the response:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response

def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = self.get_queryset()
    serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)

    response_data = {'custom_field': 'custom value',
                     'result': serializer.data}

    return Response(response_data)
```

Comment: Yes, that works. Had to import rest_framework.response.Response

Comment: Yes.. Edited :)

Comment: works like a charm! thank you.

To make the order of fields fixed, just use `OrderedDict` from `collections` library.

Comment: Also, check this answer if you need to apply [filters and pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39941573/231269) to queryset.